# Problem with this Trigonometric Equation

Tags: trigonometry

I am having trouble figuring out how to solve such an equation can anyone please tell me the steps to solve it as I have been solving a lot of trigonometric equations but I am stuck in this one:
$$\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{9}\right)=-\frac12$$

Comment: Do you know what $arcsin(-.5)$ is? Remember that $sin(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ means that $x = \frac{\pi}{6}$ so then if we have negative $-\frac{1}{2}$ then we are in the second forth quadrant so it is $-\frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{7\pi}{6}$. From there it ought to be simple.

Comment: I meant forth quadrant, not second. And we could also use $\frac{11\pi}{6}$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
$$\sin\theta=-\frac12\iff \theta\equiv-\frac\pi6\mod2\pi\;\;\text{or}\;\;\theta\equiv\frac{7\pi}6\mod2\pi$$

hence in your example we have
$$x\equiv-\frac{5\pi}{18}\mod 2\pi\;\;\text{or}\;\;x\equiv\frac{19\pi}{18}\mod2\pi$$

Comment: If I am not mistaken we could also use $\theta = \frac{11\pi}{6}$ since it is negative in the fourth quadrant as well right?

Comment: You're absolutely correct and notice that 
$$\frac{11\pi}6=-\frac\pi6+2\pi$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: let $x+\frac{\pi}{9}=y$ then you get $$\sin y=-\frac12 \Rightarrow y=-\frac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi \lor y=\frac{7\pi}{6}+2k\pi$$ where $k$ is an integer (because of the periodicity of the function $\sin y$).
Finally substitute $x+\frac{\pi}{9}=y$, and you get the solution in terms of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Take the inverse sine of both sides of the equation. You'll get $$x + \pi/9 = \sin^{-1}(-1/2)$$

Now all you need to do is to determine for what angles $\theta$, $\sin \theta = -\frac 12$.